# Angular library (with feature import support import {a1} from 'my-lib/1a' )

Tags: angular, npm, ng-packagr

I've created angular library (following official docs and some [article](https://codeburst.io/how-to-built-npm-ready-component-library-with-angular-a812a22dc1d5) ) and it worked fine. The only one thing that I was not able to do is to make it possible to import separate features like for example angular material does (`import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';`) and whenever I do `import {CustomInputModule1}` from '**my-lib**' I see that `CustomInputModule2` is also exist in final loaded chunk.

I've tried to copy different libraries ways(angular material, ngx-bootstrap) but seems that I'm missing something. With ngx-bootstrap I understood that each feature should have its own package.json?

What I want is to find out what should be the structure to make those kind of import possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone like me who did not properly google it ) It's called [secondary-entrypoint](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/secondary-entrypoints.md)